# Return type inside if loop in java

Tags: java, android, oop, logic

Can Anyone explain me how this code works.

```
  // Method returns null if bitmap not available 
    public Bitmap getBitMap(long id) {

        for ( Bitmap item : myBitmaps.keySet() ) {
            if ( item != null) {
                if ( item.getId() == id ) {
                    return item;
                }

            }
        }

        return null;
```

how come its possible to use two return (including one inside if block) in a function.sorry I am new to java.

Comment: First return its for desired result and second one is for default if you don't get desired result.

Comment: It's good practice, at least in Java, to use the "return as soon as possible" approach.  In other languages, this might not be true.

Comment: @Simon how so? I don't know of a programming language where this is not advisable...

Comment: @fge, one where there is no automatic reference counting?  Would you then duplicate the clean up code before returning?

Comment: @Simon I don't see how this is related; if you have to handle memory management yourself, it is just another constraint you have to account for; but this doesn't conflict with the "return as soon as possible" rule

Comment: Anyway -- this is not Java specific, far from it; such code can be found in pretty much all the C family of programming languages, and more

Comment: @fge Point taken.  Thanks.

Comment: @fge I withdraw my point taken ;)  See this discussion http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from

Comment: @Simon well, it is as I said: if you have to handle memory management, this is a constraint you have to account for; and that doesn't conflict at all with the "return early" rule

Comment: An `if` statement is not a **loop**.

Answer (score 6):

Simple.

The first `return` statement returns the `item` **only** if the two nested conditions are satisfied.

Once your loop is over (aka the two nested conditions are **not** satisfied), the second `return` statement triggers and returns `null`.

In short, if your `myBitmaps` `array` or `Collection` contains a `Bitmap` that is not `null` and whose `id` equals the given `id` for the method, that `Bitmap` instance is returned.

Otherwise, `null` is returned.

As **fge** mentions, a method has to fulfill all possible return paths (save for exceptional conditions).

If `null` was not returned outside your loop, the code would not compile.

This would happen because if your conditions were not fulfilled, your loop would terminate without returning anything, and so would your method.

Comment: +1. Also of importance is the fact that if the second return were not there, the code would not compile!

Answer (score 1):

When a `return` statement is called the function exits. You can have multiple `return` statements on different places because you might want to return different values depending on what happened in the function.

Answer (score 1):

At a time only one return works. When `return item` executes it actually returns the control to the statement line from where this method was called. In this case `return null` will not get execute. And when For loop executed whole and nothing happened at that time `return null` statement will get execute.

So at a time only one return statement will get execute, no matter if there is more than one return statements in a method.

Comment: that great.your explanation was easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are 3 steps:

1. Loop every `Bitmap` presents in `myBitmaps`
2. If the bitmap is 'valid' (means not `null`) continue. Otherwise, let's iterate to the next `Bitmap`.
3. If the id is the one you were looking at, return the `Bitmap`.

So what it does is: Get the Bitmap with the specified id if it exists.

Answer (score -1):

the if condition should be like this:

```
 if ( item != null && item.getId() == id){
    return item;
 }
```